# Create site collection remotely on-premises

Tags: web-services, site-collection, client-object-model

Is there any way to create a site collection remotely in an on-premises environment where self-service site collection creation is enabled?

There should be no custom web services or logic installed in SharePoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an admin web service for 2010 and 2013: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcadmin.admin.createsite%28v=office.14%29.aspx

```
http://Site/_vti_adm/Admin.asmx
```

Comment: Could it be possible to create a site collection without being a Farm Administrator? (edited question)

Comment: From this MSDN Client Object Model article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537855%28v=office.14%29.aspx, "The new client APIs do not provide administration objects or objects that are scoped higher than site collection: SPSite class in the server object model." This seems to indicate that the server object model way you would create a site collection does not have an equivalent for the client object model. I'm not sure of a way to let unprivileged users create site collections without self-service enabled, or elevating privileges, and neither of those is remote...

Comment: I was thinking of remotely filling and sending the self-service site collection creation form (using .NET WebClient.UploadValues etc), but this of course would be kind of a hack and would be great if there was another better way..

Comment: I edited the question back to original and marked this as answer as you answered correctly to the exact question (which did not rule out Farm Administrators). Creating a new question for less privileges :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Sean pointing out the web service, I was able to implement a solution using PowerShell.

The inputs to the script are as follows:

- $user - farm admin login (I am also using this as the owner of the new site collection)
- $pwd - farm admin pwd
- $adminSiteUrl - central admin site URL (must be accessible from the box where this script is running)
- $siteUrl - the full URL of the new site collection to be created
- $siteTitle - the title of the new site collection
- $username - the display name of the new site collection owner

Here's the script:

```
$securePwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pwd -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object PSCredential($user, $securePwd)
$wsdlUrl = $adminSiteUrl + "/_vti_adm/Admin.asmx?WSDL"
$svc = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $wsdlUrl -Credential $cred
$svc.Timeout = 300000    # 5 minute timeout
$svc.CreateSite(
    $siteUrl,   # URL
    $siteTitle, # Title
    "",         # Description
    1033,       # LCID
    "STS#0",    # WebTemplate
    $user,      # Owner Login
    $userName,  # Owner Name
    "",         # Owner Email
    "",         # PortalUrl
    "")         # PortalName
```

You can call DeleteSite similarly (it's simpler as it has only one parameter). I started out down the route of creating a tenant administration site for my on-prem SP2013 but was having authentication issues and fell back to this approach.